# Disabling parallel test execution when running test with coverage in Intellij

Tags: scala, testing, intellij-idea

What sbt task does intellij IDEA 14 use to run scala tests with coverage? I'm test my spark code and need to prevent them running in parallel.

I've added the following to my `build.sbt` file and it prevents tests running in parallel when they aren't generating coverage reports:

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
```

However this has no effect when running with coverage. I tried using something similar, but with `ScctTest` instead of `Test`, but sbt couldn't resolve it.

So, what coverage plugin does intellij use, and how can I disable parallel test execution when running tests with coverage? Running `sbt tasks` doesn't show anything containing the word `coverage`. I haven't enabled the `Emma` plugin in intellij - only the default `Coverage` one is enabled and it has no information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add to settings:

```
fork in ThisBuild in Test:= false
```

Comment: `Config` couldn't be found, but using `Test` works. Please update your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.